# PostgreSQL - use csv data without importing to db

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a csv file which contains some data I want to use in a psql query. I am currently able to import the data from the csv into a table in my db, but I want to make the query **without** saving the data in my db. How can I do this?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (my_csv_data)
```

Comment: Yeah, don't. Use a temporary table, much easier in real life...

Comment: Data is huge, don't want to use so much unnecessary space

Comment: You can use a foreign data wrapper: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FDW - but if the file really is "huge" then this will most probably not perform very well.

Comment: See this- http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/14/waiting-for-9-1-foreign-data-wrapper/ and http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/250-File-FDW-Family-Part-1-file_fdw.html